# Make Monte Carlo eval multithreaded for Hexgame C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, montecarlo

I am trying to make my Monte Carlo eval function multithreaded so the computer player in my hexgame will be faster. the normal code (without multithreading) is:

```
using namespace std;

int getMonteCarloEval(const State &board, Player player, int trials)
{
    vector<Move> moves = board.getMoves();
    int wins = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < trials; ++i)
    {
        State mcBoard = board;

        random_shuffle(moves.begin(), moves.end());
        for (const Move &m : moves)
            mcBoard.doMove(m);
        if (mcBoard.getWinner() == player)
            wins++;
    }

    return wins - trials / 2;
}

int getRandomEval(const State &board, Player)
{
    return rand() % 101 - 50;
}
```

With Multithreading I have this:

```
using namespace std;
vector<Move> moves;
atomic<int> wins = 0;

int getMonteCarloEval(const State &board, Player player, int trials)
{
    vector<Move> moves = board.getMoves();
    State mcBoard = board;
    size_t nr_threads = 8;
    vector<thread> workers;

    int delta = trials / nr_threads;
    int remainder = trials % nr_threads;
    int L = 0; int R = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nr_threads; i++) {
        R = L + delta;
        if (i == nr_threads - 1)
            R += remainder;
        workers.push_back(thread(mc, mcBoard, player, L, R));
        L = R;
    }
    for (auto &thread : workers) {
        thread.join();
    }

    return wins - trials / 2;
}

int getRandomEval(const State &board, Player)
{
    return rand() % 101 - 50;
}

int mc(const State &board, Player player, int L, int R)
{
    for (int i = L; i < R; i++)
    {
        State mcBoard = board;
        random_shuffle(moves.begin(), moves.end());
        for (Move m : moves)
            mcBoard.doMove(m);
        if (mcBoard.getWinner() == player)
            wins++;
    }
}
```

The problem here is, that the Computer player now is really freaking stupid. without the multithreading the Computer player plays well only very slow.
I also use Alpha Berta pruning for searching the best next step for the Computer.

Question: Does someone know what I am doing wrong with the MultiThreading?

Comment: How does the `doMove` work?

Comment: You have two variables named `moves`. One global(?) and one local in `getMonteCarloEval`. Those are not the same. Also, the thread function `mc` uses one of them without protection from the other threads, leading to data races.

Comment: @alexeykuzmin0 `void State::doMove(const Move &move)
{
 if (move.first < 0 || move.first >= size ||
  move.second < 0 || move.second >= size)
  throw "Invalid move!";
 if (hexagons[move.first * size + move.second] != Player::NONE)
  throw "Hexagon isn't empty!";
 hexagons[move.first * size + move.second] = currentPlayer;
 currentPlayer = getOpponent();
}`

Comment: Does this work with `nr_threads == 1`?